# Project GFS data to EPSG:3857

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal

I am attempting to transform the below image 1 to EPSG:3857 for use in a Leaflet map.

While the transform appears to be working it is cropping data from the top and bottom of the map. I have converted the TIFF data to a PNG before and after the reprojection to visualise the issue

[image: Image 1]

[image: Reprojected image]

I don't understand why the projection is wrong, the reprojected image seems to go from -81 to 81 instead of the normal -85 to 85 of this projection

gdalinfo of original dataset

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: ./tmp/0SFCGroundorwatersurface__Vegetation.tif
Size is 1440, 721
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",
    DATUM["unnamed",
        ELLIPSOID["Sphere",6371229,0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            ID["EPSG",9122]]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-0.125000000000000,90.125000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.250000000000000,-0.250000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -0.1250000,  90.1250000) (  0d 7'30.00"W, 90d 7'30.00"N)
Lower Left  (  -0.1250000, -90.1250000) (  0d 7'30.00"W, 90d 7'30.00"S)
Upper Right (     359.875,      90.125) (359d52'30.00"E, 90d 7'30.00"N)
Lower Right (     359.875,     -90.125) (359d52'30.00"E, 90d 7'30.00"S)
Center      ( 179.8750000,   0.0000000) (179d52'30.00"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Band 1 Block=1440x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = 0[-] SFC="Ground or water surface"
  NoData Value=9999
  Metadata:
    GRIB_COMMENT=Vegetation [%]
    GRIB_DISCIPLINE=2(Land_Surface)
    GRIB_ELEMENT=VEG
    GRIB_FORECAST_SECONDS=0 sec
    GRIB_IDS=CENTER=7(US-NCEP) SUBCENTER=0 MASTER_TABLE=2 LOCAL_TABLE=1 SIGNF_REF_TIME=0(Analysis) REF_TIME=2022-08-29T00:00:00Z PROD_STATUS=0(Operational) TYPE=0(Analysis)
    GRIB_PDS_PDTN=0
    GRIB_PDS_TEMPLATE_ASSEMBLED_VALUES=0 4 0 0 81 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 255 0 0
    GRIB_PDS_TEMPLATE_NUMBERS=0 4 0 0 81 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 255 0 0 0 0 0
    GRIB_REF_TIME=1661731200 sec UTC
    GRIB_SHORT_NAME=0-SFC
    GRIB_UNIT=[%]
    GRIB_VALID_TIME=1661731200 sec UTC
```

Edit (including more details)

To recreate my results I am using source GFS grib data from NOAA (https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p25.pl?dir=%2Fgfs.20220829%2F00%2Fatmos) and then performing the following steps:

```
gdal_translate ./tmp/FullFile.anl ./tmp/cmd.tif -of GTiff -b 531
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 ./tmp/cmd.tif ./tmp/c.tif
gdal_translate ./tmp/c.tif ./tmp/c.png -of PNG -ot Byte
```

More research:

- https://epsg.io/9001 shows that the bounds of the original are [-180 -90 180 90] which means that it cannot all be reprojected, I presume that gdal is therefore cropping the top and bottom as a safety fallback
- Still not sure how to solve this, however

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS.SE! Can you print the `meta` attribute of the source dataset?

Comment: Hey, I have added that information to the original question, should have included it initially sorry

Comment: It's ok. The domain of the EPSG:3857 projection doesn't include the poles (_projinfo_ returns `BBOX[-85.06,-180,85.06,180]]`), and the source dataset does include them. It is the expected behavior to be cropped. If you want the poles, maybe you need to think of another projection.

Comment: Okay, I see, not sure if you will be able to help further but leaflet uses EPSG:3857 and does show poles from slippy maps such as openseamaps; is it possible to transform my data to an image which displays the poles whilst being in the correct projection for leaflet?

Comment: openseamaps doesn't show the poles. But your image doesn't seem to be cropped in the same way. Also your projected image isn't a square (1249x1016), something could have gone wrong. Probably the conversion from grib to tiff file (nodes are converted to pixel centers, which makes the raster extent exceed the limits of the original system, for example with latitudes greater than 90)

Comment: `gdal.Translate('out.tif', grb, options="-of GTiff -b 1")
            gdal.Warp('out_warped.tif', 'out.tif', options="-s_srs orig.prj -t_srs .EPSG:3857")` This is the code I am using for the translation and warping, any idea why this may not be working correctly. A bit of extra information is that the result as seen above seems to extend from -81 to 81 for no apparent reason. Thanks so much for your help so far

Comment: Please include the information in the question, to be seen without reading the comments. Maybe a datum transformation between the grib sphere to WGS84. If the data is from the NOAA, they say the datum is spheric because the model shperic system, but must be interpreted as WGS84 because it is the datum of source station positions. Try with `options="-s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857"` for the _gdal.Warp()_ method.

Comment: I have included more information in the question as requested and updated it to be more general, your suggestion yielded exactly the same results unfortunately